# Error on RadioGroup onCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-group

I am creating a `custom dialog fragment` with a `radiogroup` inside. I am getting an error in the line

```
rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
```

As I've seen in my research the `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()` should just be `OnCheckedChangeListener()` but android studio detects it as an error and tell that the fix is to turn it to `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()`

here's the error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.integritynet.lukslofts.services, PID: 10341
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.integritynet.lukslofts.services/com.integritynet.lukslofts.services.main2}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                            at
>   com.integritynet.lukslofts.services.fragment.layoutChooserFragment.onCreateView(layoutChooserFragment.java:39)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>                                                                                            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5456)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

here is my code:

```
public class layoutChooserFragment extends DialogFragment {
    Context ctx;
    String rdo;
    public layoutChooserFragment(){

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_picker, container);
        getDialog().setTitle(R.string.txtLayoutChooser);

        final CheckBox cboRemember = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.cboRemember);
        RadioGroup rdoGrp = (RadioGroup)vi.findViewById(R.id.rdoGrpPckr);
        final RadioButton rdoGrid = (RadioButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.rdoGrid);
        final RadioButton rdoTab   = (RadioButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.rdoTab);
        rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (rdoTab.isChecked()) {
                    if (cboRemember.isChecked()) {
                        rdo = "tab";
                        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("chosenLayout", rdo);
                        editor.commit();
                        Log.d("tag", "chosenLayout: " + rdo);
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (rdoGrid.isChecked()) {
                    if (cboRemember.isChecked()) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, main2.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        rdo = "grid";
                        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("chosenLayout", rdo);
                        editor.commit();
                        Log.d("tag", "chosenLayout: " + rdo);
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, servicesGridStyle.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
        //dlg.show();
        return vi;

    }
}
```

Here's the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rdoGrpPckr">

    <RadioButton
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtTab"
        android:id="@+id/rdoTab"
        android:textSize="29sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtGrid"
        android:id="@+id/rdoGrid"
        android:textSize="29sp" />
</RadioGroup>

<CheckBox
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtRememberChoice"
    android:id="@+id/cboRemember"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.integritynet.lukslofts.services.fragment.layoutChooserFragment.onCreateView(layoutChooserFragment.java:39)`
Check this line. Do you have `R.id.rdoGrpPckr` in your layout? Most likely it cannot be found.

Comment: yah a have it, heres my layout

 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rdoGrpPckr">

Comment: You are mistreating the funcionality of `RadioGroup` :/ You get the `id` of the newly checked `RadioButton` - why not use it? Like `switch(checkedId){case R.id.rdoGrid: //do stuff break; case R.id.rdoTab: //do other stuff break; }`

Comment: please post Your xml layout....

Comment: you mean i use the radiobutton for the  validations and remove the radiogroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your issue is that you don't have `R.id.rdoGrpPckr` in your layout. Maybe you have another RadioGroup but with a little different id. Check out your layout xml and correct in order to fix your issue.

Also please use standard `Java class naming conventions` for your class name LayoutChooserFragment.

Comment: sorry not so used to naming convention in classes, can you suggest the proper name for it

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {}
```

rather than

```
rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {}
```

Comment: android studio tells its an error to use just OnCheckedChangeListener()

also i remember that i got two layout files, one in layout and in layout-sw600dp. the one in sw600dp is still not update. it still don't have the rdoGrp then i added it and it finally worked.     thanks @Proverbio, you reminded me of it, thanks all guys

Answer (score 0):

here's the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rdoGrpPckr">

        <RadioButton
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtTab"
            android:id="@+id/rdoTab"
            android:textSize="29sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtGrid"
            android:id="@+id/rdoGrid"
            android:textSize="29sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <CheckBox
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtRememberChoice"
        android:id="@+id/cboRemember"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you are overriding

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
```

Inside of your

```
rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {}
```

right?

I'm checking an app I did where I call from onCreate a custom function `setListeners();` where I set all the listeners.
Are you calling this functions from you onCreate? Is your radiobutton inizialized globally?

Comment: yah, so i remove @Override, how do i do it?

Comment: nono, you dont have to do that. I was just asking if you where doing it, because is the right thing to do.

Comment: i declared it inside the onCreateView. that listener is inside a DialogFragment